# Switch to Visual Mode from Script Mode - AWS Glue Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a job created earlier using AWS Glue Studio visual mode. When i open the job now, it opens only in script mode and there is no option to switch back to visual mode.
Any suggestion to switch back to visual mode will be helpful